# Is the scene where Schindler discusses miscalibrating machines taken from true events?

Tags: historical-accuracy, schindlers-list

I realize that the movie has many inaccuracies, but is this bit one of them? Is there any evidence that the Oskar Schindler wanted Germany to lose the war?